# Angular: ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: angular, npm

Why does this error occur?
I'm calling

```
 $ nx build frontend --configuration=production --skip-nx-cache
```

it is called from it

```
> ng run frontend:build:production
```

and the error comes out , what could be the problem?

```
ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you check the angular GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37748 I think they have the same problem, maybe it helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57482267/7365461 Try increasing the RAM you're providing to NodeJS processes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly go through each and everyone of your "buildable" nx libraries (libs)

Make sure that each one of them can be built in "production" mode.

Example:

```
nx run my-lib:build:production
```

Once you have found the "problem" lib - you might be in better position to figure out - why that one lib is not behaving correctly.

One thing that I found, that solved the above problem, was to remove the  "enableIvy" flag all together - as I have buildable libraries - that do not require this `false` flag

Example:

[image]